# Place on specific positions of dataframes specific values

Tags: r

```
    DF <- data.frame(x1=c(NA,7,7,8,NA), x2=c(1,4,NA,NA,4)) # a data frame with NA
    WhereAreMissingValues <- which(is.na(DF), arr.ind=TRUE) # find the position of the missing values
    Modes <- apply(DF, 2, function(x) {which(tabulate(x) == max(tabulate(x)))}) # find the modes of each column
DF
WhereAreMissingValues
Modes
```

I would like to replace the NAs of each column of DF with the mode, accordingly.
Please for some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do this.
First I'll define an helper function

```
Myfunc <- function(x) as.numeric(names(sort(-table(x)))[1L])
```

Then just use `lapply` over the data set

```
DF[] <- lapply(DF, function(x){x[is.na(x)] <- Myfunc(x) ; x})
DF
#   x1 x2
# 1  7  1
# 2  7  4
# 3  7  4
# 4  8  4
# 5  7  4
```

Comment: Or using `dplyr` `mutate_each(DF, funs(replace(.,which(is.na(.)) ,Myfunc(.))))`

Comment: @akrun, yeah, I was thinking to do this using `data.table` as in `DF[, lapply(.SD, function(x){x[is.na(x)] <- Myfunc(x) ; x})]` but thought there is no big difference because `lapply` is still `lapply`. I also don't think `dplyr` will be any better

Comment: @DavidArenburg  `replace` with `which` option used to be quicker when benchmarked in some occasions.  Not done the benchmark here.  But, anyway, it is an option, not suggesting that it will be better

Answer (score 3):

`Map` provides here a one line solution:

```
data.frame(Map(function(u,v){u[is.na(u)]=v;u},DF, Modes))

#  x1 x2
#1  7  1
#2  7  4
#3  7  4
#4  8  4
#5  7  4
```

Comment: Excellent answer that I learned something of that I didn't know and that is the map function. Thank you a lot.

Comment: This is not exactly one line solution because you need to calculate `Modes` first using `apply`.